# iPhone dev: is there any way to read from Localizable.strings file different from the current locale?

Tags: iphone, localization, localizable.strings

When developing iPhone app, is there a good way to read from Japanese Localizable.strings file when your currentLocale is not Japanese? (e.g. your current locale is Korean for example).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
[bundle pathForResource:@"Localizable"
                 ofType:@"strings"
            inDirectory:nil
        forLocalization:@"Japanese"];
```